# Mongoose returning an empty array

Tags: arrays, node.js, json, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using only find() on my server to try to retrieve data from MongoDB with mongoose, but it retrieves this `{}`, and on the console `Array(0) []`

router.js

```
const Teams =  require('./models/map');
const request = require('request');
module.exports = function(app) {

    app.get('/equipas', function(req, res) {
        Teams.find({},(err, equipas) => {
            if (err) {
                res.status(500).send();
            } else {
                equipas.sort((a,b)=>{
                    return new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date);
                })
                var array = [];
                equipas.forEach((equipa)=>{
                    array.push({
                        id: equipa.id,
                        nome: equipa.nome,
                        Coach: equipa.Coach
                    })
                })
                console.log(array);
                res.status(200).send(array);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

map.js

```
//Dependencies
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = mongoose.model('Equipas', {
    id   : String,
    nome : String,
    jogadores: Array,
    Coach: String
});
```

Comment: Did you check on db/collection name whether you're getting connected to correct DB & collection or not..

Comment: equipa is not an array. It's an object.